# PDF layout different in BIDS and on Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a report which spans multiple pages and has repeating row headers. When I preview / export the PDF in BIDS, everything looks fine, the row headers repeat on each page.

However, after deploying the report to the report server and opening it via Internet Explorer, then exporting it to PDF as well, the row headers do not show up on all pages.

I don't know if this is a general issue or if it's dependent on the tablix, subreports, ... If it's not a general issue, I can provide some screenshots as well.

Screenshots:
BIDS Development: [image: BIDS Development]

BIDS PDF Page 3: [image: BIDS PDF Page 3]

BIDS PDF Page 4: [image: BIDS PDF Page 3]

Server PDF Page 3: [image: Server PDF Page 3]

Server PDF Page 4: [image: Server PDF Page 4]

Comment: That is odd, since same PDF rendering code is used by both BIDS designer and Report Server. Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: That *is* odd. Is your server completely patched and up to date? Is the data for both reports the same? (PS. Have you triple-checked that you're running the same report on the server?)

Comment: @Jeroen The data is definitely exactly the same and it's definitely the same report (in the same version). As to the server I can't exactly tell, but I would think so, yes.

Comment: Then you probably have a problem on page 3 already: the screenshots you posted suggest the data (even before the headers problem) is different between P3 in BIDS (showing "Neue Aktiviteiten" at the bottom) and P3 on the Server (showing more rows, amongst others "Kunde/Land", "Zusammenfssung"). Perhaps that difference is causing the header problem as a side effect?

Comment: Well, the data is 100% the same. What you described is exactly my problem: The rendering there seems to be ever so slightly different, causing some fields to appear on different pages (I could live with that) and additionally not adding headers on some pages (unacceptable)

Comment: can you provide screenshots of pages 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the results from BIDS - they are often different compared to the results from Report Server. I only preview in BIDS if Remote Errors are disabled on the server.

Test by Deploying to a test site/folder.  Once you get in the swing of this it has other advantages e.g. remebering parameters, multiple windows/tabs.